# Simple tables not rendering correctly in PDF with DOMPDF converter

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using [DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf) to convert HTML to PDF. Two simple tables that are next to one another on the browser don't render on PDF the same, i.e. the second table appears in a new line. Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .simple_table { 
            width: 200px;
            float: left; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="simple_table">
             <table >
                <tr><td>table1 </td></tr>
                <tr><td>table1 </td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="simple_table">
            <table >
                <tr><td>table2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>table2</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the PHP to invoke DOMPDF converter:

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$html = file_get_contents("http://linkToAboveHTML");
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper('A4','potrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("dompdf.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float support is still an "experimental" feature of dompdf as of v0.6.1, and it's disabled by default. You can enable float support by setting the [`DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT`](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/v0.6.1/dompdf_config.inc.php#L297) configuration constant to true.

Starting in 0.6.1 you can also change settings in the instantiated object by calling the `set_option` method, e.g. `$dompdf->set_option('enable_css_float',true)`.